# How to interpolate data in Matlab when the data is not monotonically increasing (but structured)?

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I frequently use discretized curves described by vectors, say `x` and `y`, meaning that each point `(x(k),y(k))` lies on the curve. Note that `x` and `y` are generally not monotonically increasing.

Then I need to represent the data differently, because I need to know the y-values where x equals a set of given values, i.e. I want a vector `yr` for a given vector `xq` such that `(xq(k),yr(k))` are all good approximations of the original curve. So normally, interpolation would be used, however

```
yr = interp1(x,y,xq)
```

results in an error

```
The grid vectors are not strictly monotonic increasing.
```

How can I do this (in a nice way)? Note that I want to preserve the shape (connectivity between neighboring nodes) of the curve given by `x` and `y`.

## Example Problem

Say you have data representing a circle in a 2D (x,y) space. What would you do if you needed the representation of that circle on a different x-grid?

---

PS: I will provide my current approach as an answer, but welcome other approaches, especially if they are "nicer" or "simpler"? (forgive me these subjective terms)

Comment: Which version of MATLAB are you using? This works for me in R2015b: `interp1([1,3,2],[3,1,2],1.2)`.

Comment: @Dev-iL: The error is raised when the input is not unique (MatlabR2013a). Passing unsorted unique data, it is simply sorted (which is not what I assume to be expected here).

Comment: I use R2015a. Your code sample works, but not in general. It raises an error when a value appears twice in `x`. And even without the error, the output is not correct. It gives back a value that corresponds to one part of the curve, but doesn't preserve the curve per se.

Comment: Since you are dealing with what looks like parametric curves, you should look into 2d interpolation functions and not 1d. If the curves are not parametric (i.e. `y` **is** a function of `x`), consider calling [`unique` with the `'stable'` flag](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html#btb0_8v) to preserve the order of input values. Also consider [`sortrows`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html).

Comment: Please elaborate how I could use the 2D interpolation functions. y is not an explicit function of x, but rather an implicit function, i.e. F(x,y)=0. Thanks, for pointing out the `'stable'` flag on `unique`. It can definitely be used to reduce redundancy in the output vector `xr`. But how to use it for the interpolation is not immediately clear to me, so if you could explain? Thanks for your help.

Comment: My final idea: maybe try interpolating your initial `x,y` curve very finely, and then do some [nearest neighbor search](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/knnsearch.html) using your `xq` grid...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The current approach that I have works as follows. Basically, I do normal interpolation steps on pieces of the curve described by `x` and `y`.

```
% Determine whether xq is a column or row vector. This is used to make sure
% that xr and yr have the same orientation as xq.
if iscolumn(xq)
    dim = 1;
else
    dim = 2;
end

% Make sure that xq is unique and ascending
xq = unique(xq);

% Initialize xr and yr as empty arrays
[xr,yr] = deal([]);

% Loop over all [xk,xkp1]-intervals
for k = 1:length(x)-1

    % Choose values from xq that are in [xk,xkp1] (or [xkp1,xk] if
    % decreasing)
    if x(k) <= x(k+1) % x is locally increasing
        xradd = xq(x(k)<=xq & xq<=x(k+1));
    else % x is locally decreasing
        xradd = flip(xq(x(k+1)<=xq & xq<=x(k)));
        % 'flip' ensures that xradd is also decreasing (to maintain order
        % of x in xr)
    end

    % Perform local interpolation
    yradd = interp1(x(k:k+1),y(k:k+1),xradd);

    % Assemble xr and yr from local interpolations
    xr = cat(dim,xr,xradd); 
    yr = cat(dim,yr,yradd);

end
```

This method works, but there may be other methods.

Comment: This should be included in the question imho, since you are still vying for more answers, even in this answer itself.

Comment: The contents of this answer belong in the question. Your question should probably be "how can this algorithm be optimized / vectorized".

Comment: Nope, don't care about this badge thing. I have/had this problem and found no immediate answer on SO, so wanted to open the Q, but had some ideas how to solve it. So I was working on the Q and A at the same time. I think it's a useful question, but wanted to share where I got at the same time. So put it as an answer, as it is a complete solution to the question. However, I am eager to hear about alternative solutions, as I have the feeling that my solution is too long/complicated. Maybe all I need is somebody to point me to the right Matlab built-in function (that I obviously haven't found).

Comment: @Dev-iL: "how can this algorithm be optimized / vectorized": if I put it that way, people won't recognize this as a general approach to interpolating a non-monotonic curve.